# What have I done? Need to instantiate derived class in method of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a class, say `A`

```
template <typename T> class A
{
} ;
```

and a class derived from `A<T>`, (retaining type genericity)

```
template <typename T> class B : public A<T>
{
} ;
```

A situation has arisen where i need to instantiate a `B<T>` inside a method declared in `A<T>`.  Uh oh.

```
template <typename T> class A
{
    void go()
    {
        B<T> * newB = new B<T>() ; // oh boy, not working..
    }
} ;
```

What should I do and how do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break the cyclic dependency between the two classes. Trivial in this case: just define your `go()` function out of line:

```
template <typename T> class A
{
public:
    void go();
} ;

template <typename T> class B : public A<T>
{
} ;

template <typename T>
void A<T>::go()
{
    B<T> * newB = new B<T>() ;
}
```

I prefer out of line definitions, even when inlining functions, anyway because it avoids cluttering the interface with unnecessary detail. I also prefer to not have cyclic dependencies (certainly not between base and derived) but it can't always be avoided.

Comment: I tend to get linker errors whenever I try this without specifying the concrete type of `T` (as in template specialization)

Comment: Then you seem to have a tendency to do it wrong in some form... As long as the definition is in a location where it is seen when it needs to be implicitly instantiated (i.e., it is in a header) and written correctly, it will work.

Comment: Oh, ok. So the `template <typename T> void A<T>::go()` is still in the header, it just goes after `template <typename T> class B : public A<T>`. Got ya.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you'd need to explicitly instantiation because the compiler can't see the code it needs to instantiated implicitly. [Here](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/22/source-organization-of-templates/) is a write-up of how you can organize your template source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can forward-declare the class template `A` before inheriting from it -- just be sure to follow the definition of class `B` with the definition of the class `A` template in the same header:

```
template <typename T> class A;

template <typename T> class B : public A<T> {};

template <typename T> class A
{
    void go()
    {   
        B<T> * newB = new B<T>();
    }
};
```

Comment: The statement you made is wrong: You **cannot** inherit a *class* from a forward declared class. However, you **can** inherit a *class template* from a forward declared *class template* as long as the base class is defined at the point of instantiation. The reason is that the base class could actually be a specialization anyway.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thank you for your insightful comment. Class templates are indeed what I had in mind, but the terminology was off.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is write a global function that each of the `template` classes [declare friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2x4fzdz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
void go( A<T> *a )
{
    // Can now make a B<T>
    B<T> *b = new B<T>() ;
    // access b's and a's privates if this function
    // is friend to A<T> and B<T>
}
```